# Generated image display vs. download

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC action that pulls an image from a database and sends it in the response via the File(byte[], string) method.  When I navigate to the action in my browser, it downloads the file rather than display it in the browser.

I'm setting the file and setting the content type to "image/jpeg".  Is there another header that needs to be set in order to get it to do what I want it to do?

Comment: content-disposition was the header I was thinking of.  However, whenever I tried to set it, I got a NotSupportedOnThisPlatformJerk exception.  After a little reading, I found out that Controller.File() sets the content-disposition based on the file name passed in.  So, we're still in the same spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, mystery solved.

Controller.File() has an overload that takes no filename; just data and content-type.  Using that overload causes the content-disposition to be set correctly.  In retrospect, I guess that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Response.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx)

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant I set the content type, not the mime-type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to compare your response headers with a normal static JPG's response headers.  That will tell you for sure.